# Flash between splash screen and final app load for some Android phones

Tags: android, cordova, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2.3

I have a PhoneGap/Sencha Touch app that has three basic states on app load: splash screen, webview is loaded but Sencha Touch is loading, and Sencha Touch is fully loaded.

On some Android phones (such as my Kyocera Rise), everything goes smoothly. I see the splash screen, then on `deviceready`, `navigator.splashscreen.hide()` is successfully called. The html/css hardcoded loading indicator that I have on `index.html` is shown while Sencha Touch is loading, then when the Sencha Touch code is loaded it shows the fully-loaded app.

However, on other phones (such as my Galaxy S3), things do not work so well. I see the splash screen, then `deviceready` the splashscreen is hidden. However, the hardcoded loading indicator on `index.html` does not appear. All I see is a white (or sometimes black) screen. When the Sencha Touch code is fully loaded, the app does successfully appear, however.

Here's what I've tried:
- Removing various pieces of code. Removing the Sencha Touch code entirely does get rid of the flash and lets the hardcoaded loading indicator on `index.html` appear.

- Putting a few-second delay on when the Sencha Touch code fires. Didn't work
- Firing a javascript alert on `deviceready` gets rid of the flash and lets the loading indicator appear.
- Replacing the loading indicator with just text: `<body>loading</body>`. Didn't work.
- Forcing `index.html` to rerender by changing its background color as well as switching between `display:none` and `display:block`. Didn't work.
- Removing the `deviceready` listener and just running `navigator.splashscreen.hide()` right after the `<body>` markup on `index.html`. Didn't work.

Based on this information, it looks like this has something to do with Sencha Touch, since completely removing the Sencha Touch code lets the loading indicator show. Maybe has something to do with rendering as well, given that the alert indicator also lets the loading indicator show. However, that's all I've got. It looks like other people have encountered this sort of thing, primarily on iOS and Blackberry though. I haven't found any proposed solution that I've seen elsewhere that seems to fix my issue; a lot of it is just the fact that people used to not be able hide the splashscreen on deviceready.

Is there something I'm missing here? Why might this sort of thing be happening? Why would it only happen on some Android phones?

Comment: Try to move `navigator.splashscreen.hide()` to `Application.launch` method. Also, try your code in Ripple Emulator, it might help to understand what causes the problem: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ripple-emulator-beta/geelfhphabnejjhdalkjhgipohgpdnoc

Answer (score 1):

You might find yourself spending quite a long time trying to perfect this. We know the first launch of the app is rather important for UX, however (as you correctly identified) the huge number of Android devices/OS versions out there actually make it a rather daunting task. We've found one good solution is to actually hide the Sencha app while it's loading, rely on your index.html loading indicator, and then delay show the Sencha app itself.

It definitely sounds like this might be a solution for you, given you have confirmed you don't see a delay going between the Android splashscreen and the index.html loader. Depending on how exactly you are initializing your Sencha app, you probably want to hide the Ext.Viewport. I would start by putting Ext.Viewport.hide() into your initialization method. If this solves your issue, just show the Viewport again shortly delayed upon Ext.application.Launch.

Comment: Thanks for the note! So I implemented this, and the first time I ran the app it worked perfectly. However, with every other launch it does not work, even though the console.logs are printing. Did you encounter anything like this? Here's the controller code: Ext.define('BBApp.controller.Main', {
    extend:  Ext.app.Controller ,
    init: function(){
        console.log("HIDING");
        Ext.Viewport.hide();
        console.log("HIDDEN");
    },
    config: {
        refs: {
            Main: '#mainview',
            Register: '#register'
        },
        history: null
    }
    
});

Comment: Try setting the viewport to hidden from the start maybe, instead of calling Ext.Viewport.hide(). Whether you are using Ext.application() or Ext.setup(), both can take an object config for viewport. So, try setting: viewport { hidden: true }.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help here! Unfortunately, setting viewport{hidden:true} in Ext.Application does not work, nor does going right into Sencha Touch code and setting hidden:true to the core Viewport code. I feel like I may have to just let this bug go. Posted on Sencha Touch's forums, perhaps one of the folks at Sencha knows what's going on.

Comment: Sorry it didn't work, seemed to work fine in a SenchaFiddle. I will agree with your final decision, which is why I prefaced my original answer. We've been dealing with Android launchscreen flashes and workarounds/etc for years now.

Answer (score 0):

You can change sencha base color as your splash screen , don't delay app loading or dont forcefully show splashscreen.

use this css :

```
body {
 height: 100%;
 background-color: #1985D0;// change this as per your splash screen
 }
```